# Perl beats Python in fetching HTML pages?

Tags: python, html, perl

I have a Perl script which is fetching html pages. I tried rewriting it in Python (Just Coz I am trying to learn Python) and I found it to be really slow!

Here's the test Script in Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::Simple;

$url = "http://majorgeeks.com/page.php?id=";

open(WEB,">>"."perldata.txt");

for ($column = 1 ; $column <= 20 ; $column ++)

{

    $temp = $url.$column;
    print "val = $temp\n\n";

    $response=get($temp)or die("[-] Failed!!\n");

    print WEB "$response\n\n";

}
```

And here's the Equivalent Code in Python

```
import urllib2

url = "http://majorgeeks.com/page.php?id="

f = open("pydata.txt", 'w')

for i in range(20):

   tempurl = url + str(i+1)
   print "Val : " + tempurl + "\n\n"

   #req = urllib2.Request(tempurl)
   res = urllib2.urlopen(tempurl)

   f.write(res.read())

f.close()
```

The difference I found is huge!
Perl Script finished in approx 30 seconds.
While Python Script took 7mins approx. (420 seconds)!!

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, 64bit, Core i7, Tested it on a 12MBPS connection. I tried this several times, and every time I get the same amount of difference.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or I need to do something? Or the difference is justified? (I hope not)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Update 3:
I just came home and booted my laptop, ran the code again and it finished it in 11 seconds!!! :/ Was it because I "rebooted" my comp??
[Here's](https://gist.github.com/1574040#file_gistfile1.py) the Profiler output

Note - Perl still took 31 seconds for the same thing!! :/

Update 2:
As suggested by @Makoto [Here's](https://gist.github.com/1572718#file_gistfile1.txt) the profiler data That I did. And It is is really slow! I know some python configuration has to do with this, but don't know what. For one simple request, It shouldn't take 20 seconds!!!

Update : 
Fixed url to tempurl. Commented out the urllib2.Request as suggested here. Not much difference at all.

Comment: Well, I just ran some equivalent code in PHP and it completed in 16 seconds. I guess it might be the overhead of the wrapper, but it seems a bit extreme to take 7 minutes just to access 20 pages...

Comment: This won't cause such a significant slowdown, but `urllib2.urlopen` is happy to take a string (no need to create a `Request` first). Also, you're requesting `url` instead of `tempurl`. Also, why add 1 to `i` instead of just iterating through `xrange(1, 21)`?

Comment: The cause of the slowdown might be that you're being throttled by the site by requesting the same URL repeatedly (caused by getting `url` instead of `tempurl`).

Comment: @kindall I updated the code and tested. No difference. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: i ran your codes and they perform quite the same about < 30 sec.

Comment: @BPm :/ Than why am I getting such slow response? Am I doing something wrong? Like do I have to set some python parameters or something?? I am so confused now!

Comment: python took 33 sec in my computer

Comment: Try running the python code using a profiler to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @gpojd Thanks. Here's the [link](https://gist.github.com/1572718#file_gistfile1.txt) to the Output That I got. I am not sure I understand what it means though! Any clues?

Comment: @mayjune, seems more likely that something is wrong with your Python setup and/or configuration, or that something is disturbing it on your system.

Comment: "for my $column (1..20)" would make Perl version more Perl-like

Comment: @Qtax I know, what do you suggest might be the problem?

Comment: This comparison does not make any sense. - The results depend on an external variable (the Server you are fetching from). I can assure you there will be almost no difference in speed for this usecase because it is IO bound.

Comment: Please Check the new Update 3! It has confused me now....

Comment: @CanSpice, gpojd, eugeney, DonRoby, NeilKnight, What is the rationale for closing a question which is getting good discussion and interesting results? Profile statistics are not facts, optimization does not require expertise? Bad close on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Your code could be improved, although I am not sure it will fix all the performance problems:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = "http://majorgeeks.com/page.php?id={}"

with open("pydata.txt", 'w') as f:
    for i in xrange(1, 21):
        tempurl = url.format(i)
        print "Val : {}\n\n".format(tempurl)
        f.write(urlopen(tempurl).read())
```

I changed it also logically - it now requests different URLs (defined by `tempurl`), it used to request the same URL 20 times (defined by `url`). I also used string formatting, although I am not sure how it influences the efficiency.

I tested it on my system (Windows 7 64-bit, Python 2.7.2, within IDLE, moderate internet connection) and it took 40 seconds (40.262) to finish.

Comment: I tried your solution. Didn't time to compare it to mine as its still really slow. Perl finished it in 30 sec while your scripts one request is taking like 22 seconds!!!
:/ I am so disturbed by this!!

Comment: How much time its taking for the Perl script?

Comment: @mayjune: I do not have Perl installed, but processor is 2.1 GHz (AMD Turion ZM-80), so it is not as fast as yours. Also connection speed is probably half the one you have. It looks like the problem is not Python itself (it should not be). What is your Python version?

Comment: @mayjune: Also check which part of your script is the slowest - it is probably either `urllib2.urlopen()` (request for the page) or `f.write()` (writing to the file). Check it and give us the results. Or request the page separately by `import urllib2; urllib2.urlopen('http://majorgeeks.com/page.php?id=1')` and check how much time it takes.

Comment: Yeah even I don't think Python should be a problem here, But I don't know what is!
Version : Python 2.7.2+

Comment: I removed the write operations, still 4 requests took 1min 22 seconds. So It has to be urllib2 request.

I made a separate request just like you said. A two line code for just one page. 20 seconds!!!!

So its clear its urllib2.urlopen() but WHY?

Comment: @mayjune: Maybe some kind of firewall slows down your requests? Maybe some Linux administrator could give you some clues.

Comment: @Tedeck if it was some firewall issue, it would be the same for both the scripts. + I am doing this from my home, so no Admin or Firewall or anything I am using. Anywhere Else I should check? Coz I know fault is from my side, just don't know what!

Comment: @mayjune Chek if it's proxy in system environment $ `export | grep -i proxy`

Comment: @reclosedev here's what I Got
`declare -x UBUNTU_MENUPROXY="libappmenu.so"`

What does it mean?

Comment: @mayjune: Firewall is able to accept some rules for filtering specific packets, you can configure it to make what you wish. I still think this is one of the possibilities.

Comment: @Tadeck Please Check the new Update 3! It has confused me now....

Comment: @mayjune: So there was no problem with Python altogether, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I still have to scratch my head and figure out why this code is taking so long for both @mayjune and @Tadeck.  I've had a chance to run both pieces of code formally through a profiler, and here are the results.  I strongly encourage you to run these results for yourself on your machine, since mine will produce different results (AMD Athlon II X4 @3GHz, 8GB RAM, Ubuntu 11.04 x64, 7Mbit line).

To run:

`python -m cProfile -o profile.dat <path/to/code.py>; python -m pstats profile.dat`

(From inside of the profiler, you can check `help` for commands.)

---

### Original Code:

```
Fri Jan  6 17:49:29 2012    profile.dat

20966 function calls (20665 primitive calls) in 13.566 CPU seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time
List reduced from 306 to 15 due to restriction <15>

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
1    0.001    0.001   13.567   13.567 websiteretrieval.py:1(<module>)
20    0.000    0.000    7.874    0.394 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:122(urlopen)
20    0.000    0.000    7.874    0.394 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:373(open)
20    0.000    0.000    7.870    0.394 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:401(_open)
40    0.000    0.000    7.870    0.197 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:361(_call_chain)
20    0.000    0.000    7.870    0.393 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:1184(http_open)
20    0.001    0.000    7.870    0.393 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:1112(do_open)
1178    7.596    0.006    7.596    0.006 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
20    0.000    0.000    5.911    0.296 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:953(request)
20    0.000    0.000    5.911    0.296 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:974(_send_request)
20    0.000    0.000    5.911    0.296 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:938(endheaders)
20    0.000    0.000    5.911    0.296 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:796(_send_output)
20    0.000    0.000    5.910    0.296 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:769(send)
20    0.000    0.000    5.909    0.295 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:751(connect)
20    0.001    0.000    5.909    0.295 /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py:537(create_connection)
```

...so from observation, the only thing that could slow you down is...`urlopen` and `open`.  I/O is slow, so that's sort of understandable.

### Revised Code

```
Fri Jan  6 17:52:36 2012    profileTadeck.dat

21008 function calls (20707 primitive calls) in 13.249 CPU seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time
List reduced from 305 to 15 due to restriction <15>

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
1    0.002    0.002   13.249   13.249 websiteretrievalTadeck.py:1(<module>)
20    0.000    0.000    7.706    0.385 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:122(urlopen)
20    0.000    0.000    7.706    0.385 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:373(open)
20    0.000    0.000    7.702    0.385 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:401(_open)
40    0.000    0.000    7.702    0.193 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:361(_call_chain)
20    0.000    0.000    7.702    0.385 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:1184(http_open)
20    0.001    0.000    7.702    0.385 /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py:1112(do_open)
1178    7.348    0.006    7.348    0.006 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
20    0.000    0.000    5.841    0.292 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:953(request)
20    0.000    0.000    5.841    0.292 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:974(_send_request)
20    0.000    0.000    5.840    0.292 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:938(endheaders)
20    0.000    0.000    5.840    0.292 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:796(_send_output)
20    0.000    0.000    5.840    0.292 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:769(send)
20    0.000    0.000    5.839    0.292 /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py:751(connect)
20    0.001    0.000    5.839    0.292 /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py:537(create_connection)
```

Again, the largest two culprits of time being spent are on `urlopen` and `open`.  This leads me to believe that I/O has a major role in bogging down your code.  However, the difference is not substantial on the machine that I've tested it on - **Perl's script executes in roughly the same time.**

```
real    0m11.129s
user    0m0.230s
sys 0m0.070s
```

I'm not convinced that it's software's fault that your code is slow, although your machine is pretty beefy.  I strongly encourage you to run the profiler suite (code is included above) to see if you can find any bottlenecks that I've missed.

Comment: @Maketo I am sure it has to do something with my setup/config somewhere in the system, I am not sure what. I did a little profiling thing here's the [link](https://gist.github.com/1572718#file_gistfile1.txt)

Comment: @mayjune It seems more and more like it's something in your configuration after all.  I just ran similar code (and I encourage you to edit *that* profile result into your main question), and it took a half a second.

Comment: @Makoto This is an interesting problem. On my work machine, perl took ~4 seconds and python took ~1 second. At home, perl took ~5.5 seconds and python took ~6.5 seconds. The only difference I see is that ping response from work is 6.5ms and 35ms from home. Based on http://bugs.python.org/issue4879 , there may be some TCP buffering issues.

Comment: @casevh, I sure hope it doesn't boil down to that.  Those kinds of things can be tricky to pinpoint and track down.

Comment: @Makoto Check the new Profiler Data I have updated in the main post. Code finished in 11 seconds while perl too 30 seconds!!

Comment: @Makoto Both perl and Python are taking ~5.5 seconds. I used Wireshark to capture the packets to/from the web site. No practical difference. Each web page takes just over .25 seconds to download. There is no delay between web page requests. It looks like network I/O is the primary source of delay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know, why are you getting this strange results. But let me to advice really fast solution. Use some asynchronous lib. I like [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), with very beautiful [interface in request library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests)

Code:

```
from requests import async
import time

begin = time.time()
url = "http://majorgeeks.com/page.php?id=%s"
rs = [async.get(url % i) for i in xrange(1, 21)]
responses = async.map(rs, size=10)

with open("pydata.txt", 'w') as f:
    for response in responses:
        print response.url
        f.write(response.content)

print 'Elapsed:', (time.time()-begin)
```

It takes only 2.45 seconds.

**EDIT**

Possible causes of slow `urllib2.urlopen`:

- `http_proxy` in system environment
- site slowdowns somehow `urllib2` agent, to limit automated crawling

Comment: Thanks Though the problem is not that, i'll try this to increase the speed. Please Check the new Update 3! It has confused me now....